# Select an option from DDL, then click a radio button and the table from DB should display for selected item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body  onload="myFunction()">
        <form method="post">
            <label for="venue">Venue</label>

            <?php

            $stmt = $conn->prepare( "select venue_name from venue_master" );
            $stmt->execute();
            //set the resulting array to associative
            $result_vm = $stmt->fetchAll();


            echo "<select name='ddlvenue'>";
            echo "<option>-Select-</option>";
            foreach ( $result_vm as $row ) {
                echo "<option>" . $row[ "venue_name" ] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";


            ?>

            <input type="radio" name="ltbbtn" id="ltdbudp" value=""/><label>Limited Budget Packages</label>

            <td><input type="radio" name="designbud" id="dbudp" value=""/><label>Design your own</label>

            <br/>

            <div class="packages" style="width: 60%;margin: auto;display: none;">

            </div>
            <br/>

            <input type="submit" class="enquirybtn" name="generatebtn" value="Generate Enquiry" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a part of my code; it may be not clear to you all but my question is that there is a drop down list whose options came from database. Here the names in options are Rochester and Holland Village. And then there are two radio buttons named Limited Budget and Design your own.

I want that if I select a option from the drop down list and then click on the first radio button — for example, I select Rochester from DDL and click the Radio button Limited budget — then a table should display from database which is created for Rochester. If I select Holland Village and click the radio button, then its table should display.

But I am unable to correlate the radio button and selected item value together so that table can be displayed.

Comment: Why don't your input elements have values?

Comment: the options in drop down list will come from database
and here is a part of code